# Unable to load variable in list view

Tags: json, dart, flutter

Description: I’m trying to display a value from a json file in a ListView. I’ve made a class to read the json file and obtain the value from the key. This works fine, but, I’m unable to carry the key value into the ListView. I obtain the key value using a separate class called “EmployeeInfo” and read the json file contents using a method called “jsonContent”. So far, I can instantiate the class, exeute the method and print out the class variables onto the console. However, I’m unable to load this class variable value into the ListView title.

I’m unable to load my variable in this code but was able to print through the :print(jsonrd.EmployeeJson[“Name”]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:emas_app/Dependant.dart' as Dep;

import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(new Fourth());



class Fourth extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  MemberInfoState createState() => new MemberInfoState();
}
class MemberInfoState extends State<Fourth>{
  List  data;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var  jsonrd = new Dep.EmployeeInfo(); // Go to the house and open the door
    jsonrd.jsonContent(); // E

    return new Scaffold(

      body:  new Container(

        child: new Center(
          child:new FutureBuilder(
            future: DefaultAssetBundle
                .of(context)
                .loadString('assets/MemberInfo.json'),
            builder: (context,snapshot){

              var mydata = JSON.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
              print("mydata: " + mydata.toString());
              var jsondata = new Dep.EmployeeInfo();
              jsondata.jsonContent();
              final name = jsondata.EmployeeJSON["Name"].toString();

              return new ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder:(BuildContext context,int index){
                  return new Card(
                    child:new Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new ListTile(
                          title: new Text("Name " ),
                          subtitle: new Text(name),
                        ),
                        new ListTile(
                          title: new Text("Identification " ),
                          subtitle: new Text(  mydata[index]["Employee"]["Identification"]),
                        ),
                        new ListTile(
                          title: new Text("Company " ),
                          subtitle: new Text(  mydata[index]["Employee"]["Company"]),
                        ),
                        new ListTile(
                          title: new Text("Date Of Birth " ),
                          subtitle: new Text(  mydata[index]["Employee"]["DateOfBirth"]),
                        ),

                        const Divider(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          height: 50.0,
                        ),

                        new MaterialButton(
                            color: Colors.indigo,
                            height:50.0,
                            minWidth: 50.0,
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            child: new Text("More"),
                            onPressed: () => print(jsonrd.EmployeeJSON["Name"])

                            ),
                      ],

                    ),

                  );





                },
                itemCount: mydata ==  null ? 0 : mydata.length,
              );


            },
          ),
//
//
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Calling Json (Code):

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


final String url = "http://crm.emastpa.com.my/MemberInfo.json";
List depData;



class EmployeeInfo {
//  String jsonContent;
  List data;
  String Employee;
  String empname;
  String empdep;
  Map <String, dynamic> EmployeeJSON = new Map<String, dynamic>();

  void jsonContent() {

    Future<String> getData() async {
      var res = await http.get(
          Uri.encodeFull("http://crm.emastpa.com.my/MemberInfo.json"),
          headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

      var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
      this.data = resBody;

      this.EmployeeJSON = resBody[0]["Employee"];
      Employee = resBody[0]["Employee"]["Name"];
      depData = resBody[0]["Dependents"];

      this.empname = this.EmployeeJSON["Name"];
      this.empdep= depData[0]["Dependents"];
      return "Success!";
    }
    getData();
  }

}
```

The output
Performing hot reload...
I/flutter (24432): mydata: null
Reloaded 8 of 549 libraries in 1,696ms.
I/flutter (24432): mydata: null
I/flutter (24432): mydata: null
I/flutter (24432): mydata: null
I/flutter (24432): mydata: null
Lost connection to device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, your code was really difficult. You were executing a future inside the build method, not only expecting its result in the FutureBuilder.

I have made a profound modification still maintaining the spirit of what you wanted to do.

But you should really create a Future that returns a list of Employees instead of handling the html response inside the FutureBuilder.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

final String url = "http://crm.emastpa.com.my/MemberInfo.json";

class EmployeeInfo {
  String Employee;
  String empname;
  String empdep;
  Map<String, dynamic> EmployeeJSON = new Map<String, dynamic>();
}

Future<String> jsonContent() async {
  var res = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull("http://crm.emastpa.com.my/MemberInfo.json"),
      headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
  return res.body;
}

void main() => runApp(new Fourth());

class Fourth extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MemberInfoState createState() => new MemberInfoState();
}

class MemberInfoState extends State<Fourth> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new Container(
          child: new Center(
            child: new FutureBuilder<String>(
              future: jsonContent(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot?.hasData) {
                  var mydata = json.decode(snapshot.data);
                  final name = mydata[0]["Employee"]["Name"];

                  return new ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return new Card(
                        child: new Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new ListTile(
                              title: new Text("Name "),
                              subtitle: new Text(name),
                            ),
                            new ListTile(
                              title: new Text("Identification "),
                              subtitle: new Text(
                                  mydata[index]["Employee"]["Identification"]),
                            ),
                            new ListTile(
                              title: new Text("Company "),
                              subtitle: new Text(
                                  mydata[index]["Employee"]["Company"]),
                            ),
                            new ListTile(
                              title: new Text("Date Of Birth "),
                              subtitle: new Text(
                                  mydata[index]["Employee"]["DateOfBirth"]),
                            ),
                            const Divider(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              height: 50.0,
                            ),
                            new MaterialButton(
                              color: Colors.indigo,
                              height: 50.0,
                              minWidth: 50.0,
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                              child: new Text("More"),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: mydata == null ? 0 : mydata.length,
                  );
                } else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```